# Max number in each row sometimes displays the right values and otherwise (C language)

Tags: c, arrays, max, rows

I need to make a simple program which will count the max number of each row.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(){
int lentele[50][50],x,y,n;
int maxx[50], maxy[50], max_value[50];

printf("Enter one number which will determine how many rows and columns your table will have:");
scanf("%d", &n);


for (y=1; y<=n; y++){
    for (x=1; x<=n; x++){
        scanf("%d", &lentele[y][x]);
        if (max_value[y] < lentele[y][x]){
        max_value[y]=lentele[y][x];
        maxx[y]=x;
        maxy[y]=y;
        }
    }
}

for (y=1; y<=n; y++){
    for (x=1; x<=n; x++){
    printf("%d\t", lentele[y][x]);
    }
printf("\n");
}

for (x=1; x<=n; x++){
printf("Max in %d row: %d (%d,%d)", x, max_value[x], maxx[x], maxy[x]);
printf("\n");
}
}
```

The problem is, few rows are calculated correctly, and the others display strange big numbers like 23123.

Here are some of the input & output examples:
I enter number: `2`

It means that it will have 2 rows and 2 columns.
Now I will enter 4 different numbers:
I enter:

```
1
2
3
4
The output is: (first it displays how the table looks like and then the results)
1   2   
3   4   

Max in 1 row: 2 (2,1)
Max in 2 row: 4 (2,2)
```

Now if I try the same thing one more time:

I enter:

```
1
2
3
4
The output is: (first it displays how the table looks like and then the results)
1   2   
3   4


Max in 1 row: 2 (2,1)
Max in 2 row: 1537186176 (1539574368,8)
```

Could you tell me what's wrong? I don't want a simplified code, I would like to know what is not right here.

Comment: You need to initialize your arrays

Comment: A sporadic behavior like this is a clear indicator of an uninitialized value being read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code does not initialise `max_value[50]` to `0` or even better to `INT_MIN` if you plan to enter negative numbers too.

Simply add the initialiser to the declaration by doing:

```
#define VALUES_MAX (50)

int max_value[VALUES_MAX] = {0}; /* Default all array elements to zeros, 
                            which is suffcient for comparing to positve numbers. */

/* If comparsion to negativ number hall be performed set all array elements to INT_MIN. */
for (size_t i = 0; i < VALUES_MAX; ++i)
{
  max_value[i] = INT_MIN;
}
```

`INT_MIN` is defined in `<limits.h>`.

Comment: thank you very much, i will upvote your comment when i'll have enough reputation.

Comment: @TomasDžiovėnas: Please see the relevant update to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`max_value` has not be initialized when this statement is executed:

```
if (max_value[y] < lentele[y][x]){
```

This is one way to fix it, assuming the values are positive.

```
int maxx[50], maxy[50], max_value[50] = { 0 };
```

Comment: if it is not hard, could you please explain what the number zero does in your given exaple, and by the way thank you. Does it make all the array values 0 ? like for example max_value[1] = 0, max_value[2] = 0, am i right?

Comment: It just initializes all the entries in max_value to be zero. As it was, your code was reading entries in max_value that were just garbage values, C does not initialize your arrays for you.

Comment: @CharlieBurns: Nitpicking: `T array[<some_size_greater_1>] = {0}` sets the first element to `0` and as the other elements do not get any  initialisers anymore from the braces they are initialised as if they were declared `static` which in fact is also `0`. See my answer on how initilaising to `INT_MIN`.

Comment: @alk, right. Got it. I misunderstood your comment at first. Thanks.